# Apache can't GET a file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, migration

I've a strange problem with Apache. I migrated a few websites from one to another HW (and  from Centos 5 to Centos 6), there are only PHP code and some databases.. Everything is ok and running, except for one site (VirtualHost).

Apache can't load static files (simple images). At server-status I see a lot of "Sending Reply" (W) statuses via GET with this files, apache run on 100% of cpu, load is really high.

I compared (I think) all config files on both server (*looks ok*), was founding filesystem errors (*no errors*) and was comparing md5sum on old and new server (*it's ok too*).

Do you have any idea what can be bad?

Comment: paste some apache logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the access and error logs? I would do that first. I would also try disabling any .htaccess files used by that virtualhost. Could be some bad rules or php flags the new server doesn't like.

Comment: Oh yes, there was an error with redirecting at .htaccess. But no relevant lines in error or acces or any others logs..